# How does this code calculate 4 to the power of <exponent>

Tags: python, lambda, functional-programming

I'm following *Bioinformatics I* on Coursera. One of my fellow students used functional programming to solve a `pattern_to_number` problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from functools import reduce

def pattern_to_number(pattern):
    code = dict(zip("ACGT",range(4)))
    return reduce(lambda x,c: 4*x+code[c], pattern, 0)

print(pattern_to_number(sys.argv[1]))
```

This is how I run the little program locally:

`$ python3 ./pattern_to_number.py 'ATGCAA'`

And the output is ( correct ): `912`

I understand `lambda` and the use of `reduce`. I don't understand how the functional solution above is able to mimic the functionality of the following traditional approach. Where 4 to the power of `i` gets calculated.

```
for i, val in enumerate(pattern[::-1]):
        total += dict[val] * (4**i)
```

So where ( or how ) does the body of the lambda calculate 4 to the power of `code[c]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's take a look at the reduce function:

```
reduce(lambda x,c: 4*x+code[c], pattern, 0)
```

This will multiply the current value by `4` and add the current element from the pattern. Writing this out would look something like this:

1. `x=0` (Initial value) `c="A"`, result is: `4*x+code["A"] = code["A"]`
2. `x=code["A"]` (previous result) `c="C"`, result is `4*x+code["C"] = 4*code["A"] + code["C"]
3. `x=4*code["A"] + code["C"]`, `c="G"`, result is `4*x+code["G"] = 4*(4*code["A"] + code["C"]) + code["G"] = 4**2 * code["A"] + 4 * code["C"] + code["G"]`
4. `x=4**2 * code["A"] + 4 * code["C"] + code["G"]`, `c="T"`, result is `4*x+code["T"] = 4*(4**2 * code["A"] + 4 * code["C"] + code["G"]) + code["T"] = 4**3 * code["A"] + 4**2 * code["C"] + 4 * code["G"] + code["T"]`

Which has the correct powers of `4` for each of the sequence elements.

So the trick lies in the `4*x` of the `reduce` function, which ends up multiplying the first element in the pattern by `4` exactly `len-1` times, the second element by 4 `len-2` times etc.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Looking at it using the basic building blocks was refreshing.

Comment: The method used by my fellow student is called [Horner's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).